# Why use CC_BREAK_IF?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm learning cocos2d-x, and I have a legibility question about it. Why you guys use a macro that only does a break? What is the benefit of this?

Sorry to ask such lame question, but I got really intrigued about this, as it took more then I thought it would to understand a sample code thanks to macros like these..

Answer (score 1):

The macro sounds like a programmatic breakpoint (**not** a break statement) that triggers on the given condition. Application halts and you can debug from there. Same as setting a breakpoint in the IDE.

Comment: ok, maybe my C skills are too poor, but are you sure it isn't a brake statement? - #define  CC_BREAK_IF(cond)   if(cond) break

Comment: in that case it's a break .... and poor programming practice to create a macro for such a purpose, probably just to save one line of code.